# Using Python Graphene to set a value and get several values

Tags: python, python-2.7, graphene-python

I want to set up a graphene python API which would let the user query the host, registrar, or both, when provided with a domain name.  At this point, I just want to be able to access the passed in domainname in any of the other `resolve` methods.

Seems I cant use `self` to store the passed in domainname, as that evaluates to `None`.

Any suggestions to the following code would be appreciated...

```
import graphene


class DomainInput(graphene.InputObjectType):
    dname = graphene.String()


class DomainName(graphene.ObjectType):
    name = graphene.String()


class Host(graphene.ObjectType):
    name = graphene.String()


class Registrar(graphene.ObjectType):
    name = graphene.String()


class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    domainname = graphene.Field(Host, domain=DomainInput())
    host = graphene.String()
    registrar = graphene.String()

    def __init__(self):
        self.domain_name = ''

    def resolve_domainname(self, args, context, info):
        domain = args.get('domain')
        self.domain_name = domain.get('dname')
        return DomainName(name='For domain name: {}'.format(self.domain_name))

    def resolve_host(self, args, context, info):
        return Host(name='HOST for '.format(self.domain_name))

    def resolve_registrar(self, args, context, info):
        return Registrar(name='REGISTRAR for '.format(self.domain_name))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    di = graphene.Schema(query=Query)
    query = '''
        query something{
            domainname(domain: {dname:"a.com"}) { name }
            host
            registrar
        }
    '''
    result = di.execute(query)

    print result.data
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import graphene


class DomainName(graphene.Interface):
    name = graphene.String()
    domain = ''


class HostInfo(graphene.ObjectType):
    class Meta:
        interfaces = (DomainName,)

    def resolve_name(self, args, context, info):
        # Code to get the hosting provider
        return 'The Host for {}'.format(self.domain)


class RegistrarInfo(graphene.ObjectType):
    class Meta:
        interfaces = (DomainName,)

    def resolve_name(self, args, context, info):
        # Code to get the registrar
        return 'The Registrar for {}'.format(self.domain)


class DomainQuery(graphene.ObjectType):
    host = graphene.Field(HostInfo)
    registrar = graphene.Field(RegistrarInfo)
    domain = graphene.String()

    def resolve_host(self, args, context, info):
        domain = HostInfo()
        domain.domain = self.domain
        return domain

    def resolve_registrar(self, args, context, info):
        domain = RegistrarInfo()
        domain.domain = self.domain
        return domain


class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    domain_query = graphene.Field(DomainQuery, domain=graphene.String(required=True))

    def resolve_domain_query(self, args, context, info):
        return DomainQuery(domain=args.get('domain'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    di = graphene.Schema(query=Query)
    query = '''
        query{
            domainQuery(domain: "a.com") {
                domain
                host {
                    name
                }
                registrar {
                    name
                }
            }
        }
    '''
    result = di.execute(query)

    print result.data
```

This will return the following:

```
OrderedDict([('domainQuery', OrderedDict([('domain', u'a.com'), ('host', OrderedDict([('name', 'The Host for a.com')])), ('registrar', OrderedDict([('name', 'The Registrar for a.com')]))]))])
```